# DNS blackout issue in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dns, 22.04

I've been using Ubuntu 16, 18 and then 20 for many years with the same ISP. Recently, I bought a new machine and had to update to Ubuntu 22 as the WiFi drivers were not available on earlier versions.

Every few hours I'm getting `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` errors on my (chrome) browser and using `dig website.com` would fail even though `dig @8.8.8.8 website.com` would return correct record and 8.8.8.8 is **also** part of the DNS servers retuned by DHCP.

This is fixed by itself if I press Ctrl+Shift+R for 10 seconds, or if I change `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I can't help but think this is a regression introduced in Ubuntu 22.04, anyone else has any experience with this?

Some logs from `journalctl`:

```
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-51 noise=9999 txrate=135000

Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.

Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
```